# How to present a view Controller from a container View?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, view, uiviewcontroller

I have a container View where the upper half shows some details and th lower half shows the navigation to a particular place.

A is my View Controller with a container View , Now i have B View Controller which occupies bottom Half of the A View Controller. I have another View Controller C which is being presented from B, but instead of occupying the bottom half , it occupies entire screen. How can i fix it so that whatever happens after interaction fro View Controller B it stays in the bottom half of the screen ?

In the bottom half the view controller first takes in a few values and them presents a view Controller.

[image: This is my first View Con with Container View]

Now when i present a new View Controller it occupies entire screen

[image]

```
Directions.shared.calculate(options) { (waypoints, routes, error) in
            guard let route = routes?.first else { return }

            let viewController = NavigationViewController(for: route)

            self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

Comment: Hi there- how are you setting the frames for your view hierarchy? Have you looked at the API for NavigationViewController and checked whether you can customise the frame for its view? https://mapbox.github.io/mapbox-navigation-ios/navigation/0.4.0/Classes/NavigationViewController.html#/s:vC16MapboxNavigation24NavigationViewController7mapViewGSqCSo10MGLMapView_

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found out a way. Just writing up incase any one would require.

I just embedded my View Controller B into a Navigation Controller and

```
let viewController = NavigationViewController(for: route)


 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```